# Replace consecutive digits with #

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java string with letters, symbols, and digits. I'd like to replace all instances of consecutive digits with a single # symbol. Any non-digit character between numbers needs to be ignored though. How do you turn `in` to `out`?

```
String in = "Im5/11 blah 1234567";
String out = "Im#/# blah #";
```

Comment: `in.replaceAll("\\d+", "#")`.

Comment: As a follow up, how do I replace only instances where there are 2 or fewer consecutive digits? So I want `out="Im#/# blah 1234567"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with the regex, `\\d+`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = "Im5/11 blah 1234567";
        System.out.println(in.replaceAll("\\d+", "#"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Im#/# blah #
```